# Adding Token to Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Im new to react and javaScript so i want to know how can i store a token in localstorage from an api login post.

this is my login service

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
try {
    const result = await fetch(
        '',
        {
            method: 'Post',
            body: JSON.stringify({ login: email, senha: password }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default',
        },
    );
    const data = await result.json();

    return data;
    
} catch (err) {
    return err;
}};
```

And this is my loginhandler

```
const loginHandler = async () => {
    const result = await login(email, password);
    console.log(result);
    
};
```

this is the console output when i connect to the api with a valid user

```
{message: {…}, response: {…}}
```

message: {text: "Login efetuado com sucesso.", type: "Sucess"}
response:
result: {token: "eyJhbGciiOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfb…jZSpJ9.hDRKzbr4GIoPQgbqXr7BRcGCov1_jN0_PyyG4a99HohE", id: "dd668be7-0d2c-406a-a679-deabde770481", email: "manager@gmail.pt", name: "Manager", rgpdAccept: true}
**proto**: Object
**proto**: Object

Comment: just type storage.setItem(token, result?.response?.result?.token);

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: i cahnged the result to data and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
localStorage.setItem("token" , "eyJhbGciiOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfb…jZSpJ9.hDRKzbr4GIoPQgbqXr7BRcGCov1_jN0_PyyG4a99HohE")
```

Comment: yes but the token changes every 2 hours theres a way to do this instead of putting manually (adding the token parameter to a variable for example)